# Translator resource in a non global region

Tags: region, microsoft-translator

I created a Translator resource with a specific region (non global) (example: eastus).
when I'm calling the global api "api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com", its guaranteed it will be processed on the specific region? or at least in the same geo?
Or I should use the specific geo url (such as "api-nam.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com")

- I'm sending this header as part of the request "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region:"
- Example url I'm using: https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=en

+what happens on cases of disasters and BCDR? the call is guaranteed to be called within the Geo? or it will just fail?

Comment: you have to call the regional endpoint for regional resources. For disasters, it will fail over within the same region (or fail if all DC's in the same region are down)

Comment: your resource should have a custom endpoint, when created in a specific region. This is the endpoint you need to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/reference/v3-0-reference#base-urls

Answer (score 1):

Translator is a non-regional (global) service.

However, it allows user to force requests among DCs using geographical endpoints. Which DCs handle requests for various endpoints as documented here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#base-urls